# Center page layout with CSS

Tags: web-applications

1. Launch a text editor(Notepad),and open the javajam.css file. Add a style for an id named wrapper with width set to 80%, margin-right set to auto, and margin-left set to auto.
2. Launch a text editor, and open the index.html file. Add the HTML code to configure a div element assigned to the id wrapper that "wraps" or contains, the code within the body section. Save and test your index.html page in a browser and you'll notice that the page content is now centered within the browser viewport as shown in Figure 3.27( https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l4Em.jpg)

What is wrong with my index.html file I cant center the body?
Index. html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title> JavaJam Coffee House </title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="javajam.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">  
       <header>
        <h1> JavaJam Coffee House </h1>
    </header>
    <nav>   
            <b><a href="index.html">Home</a> &nbsp; 
            <a href="menu.html">Menu</a> &nbsp; 
            <a href="Music.html">Music</a> &nbsp;
            <a href="Jobs.html">Jobs</a></b>
        </nav>

        <ul>
            <li>Specialty Coffee and Tea</li>
            <li>Bagels, Muffins, and Organic Snacks</li>
            <li>Music and Poetry Readings</li>
            <li>Open Mic Night</li>
        </ul>
        <p>12312 Main Street<br>
        Mountain Home, CA 93923<br>
        1-888-555-5555<br>
        </p>

    <footer>
        Copyright &copy; 2014 JavaJam Coffee House<br>
        <a href="mailto ImaniJackson@gmail.com">ImaniJackson@gmail.com</a>

    </footer>       
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javajam.css

```
body { background-color: #FFFFCC;
       color: #330000;
       font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
header { background-color: #CCAA66;
         color: #000000;
         text-align: center; }

h1 { line-height: 200%; }
nav { text-align: center; }
footer { background-color: #CCAA66;
         color: #000000;
         font-size: .60em; 
         font-style: italic;
         text-align: center; }
#wrapper { width: 80%;
           margin-left: auto;
           margin-right: auto; }
```

Comment: Do you want to centre the text? Or keep the text left aligned and make the wrapper doc centred on the page?

Comment: @Lee I want to center the text

Comment: You have no text align centre rule for the wrapper div

Comment: @Lee The bullets arent right next to i.e. the specialty,coffee and tea stuff http://i.imgur.com/hDq3VlC.jpg